# Meaning of "hit somewhere"

Tags: difference

In some song (it was like summer party song), they say:

> We'll hit the beach, yeah, we'll hit the beach.

What's the meaning of ***hit*** in those sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this definition, which is found at the end of a very long list on the [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/hit) page:

> **hit** (*v.*) reach a destination, either real or abstract

This is why a singer might say:

> *We’ll hit the beach, yeah, we’ll hit the beach*

while a project manager might say:

> We think we’ll hit the first milestone next month.

Comment: We'll reach our destination, yeah, we'll reach our destination.

Answer (score 2):

The verb **hit** in that context is a colloquial expression that means "visit".

> I'll be there in a minute. I have to hit the john.
>
> We are going to Paris and plan to hit the Louvre.

If used enthusiastically, it still has the same basic meaning but can connote extra energy; it might be paraphrased as "to storm onto" or "to run out onto".

> They pulled into the seaside parking lot. It had been a very long ride. The boys hopped out of the car and yelled "Let's hit the beach!".